# Background TCP server to collect data

Tags: multithreading, server, tcp

I have an OpenGL application that plots data in real time.  I would like to have a background TCP server that will accept data from a client without blocking on a call.  The data is originally an array of 2048 doubles.  Once this array of data arrives, I need to place it in a circular array buffer that is read from the foreground OpenGL program.

I initially tried the [async TCP server code from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx) but this code blocks on the `listener.BeginAccept`.

I thought that this code would operate in the background but obviously not.  So I need to run the server in a background thread and not block on a read.  I could use a much simpler server since I only have one client at a time to deal with.

Now the circular array buffer is a static class.  To write to it it is a simple `CircularBuffer.Write(double buffer);`  The class takes care of all indexes.

So what I need is a thread safe TCP server running in the background which can write to this circular buffer.  I assume I might need to have some locking mechanism?

Can you suggest an over approach to this please?

Comment: I think you should elaborate more your problem and separate each problem in one question, because there are a lot of concerns to made it work.  Maybe this article can help you with TCP server side: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/12/15/awaiting-socket-operations/

Comment: Thanks. Actually the circular buffer is taken care of with a locking mechanism. I just need the tcp side.

Comment: TCP is quite low level. You might want to think about WCF.

Comment: I don't know. I haven't seem any examples about binary data.  Seems it's all xml or streaming.  But then even then seems pretty inefficient to send biary data. I could be wrong I guess.

Comment: @Tom I use it with binary data all the time -- you can chose the encoding to some extent. It does not have to be strings. I have found it quite efficient.